# Why don't I get compiler errors on unused local variables?

Tags: compiler-errors, d, language-lawyer, declaration, local-variables

The [Dlang documentation](https://dlang.org/spec/function.html#local-variables) states:

> It is an error to declare a local variable that is never referred to.
>   Dead variables, like anachronistic dead code, are just a source of
>   confusion for maintenance programmers.

I've compiled the following code in `ldc 0.14`, `gdc 5.1`, and `dmd 2.067.1`:

```d
void main()
{
    int i;
    //local variable i not used...
}
```

I didn't get any compiler errors.  Should this fail to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of those error things aren't actually implemented. They are things that would be nice and the compiler writers reserve the right to make errors (with the justification that according to spec, your code is wrong anyway), but haven't actually done... and maybe never will actually do.

> It is an error to use a local variable without first assigning it a value. The implementation may not always be able to detect these cases. Other language compilers sometimes issue a warning for this, but since it is always a bug, it should be an error.

That's not implemented and probably never will be since people depend on the auto initialization as a feature.

> It is an error to declare a local variable that is never referred to. Dead variables, like anachronistic dead code, are just a source of confusion for maintenance programmers.

Not implemented

> It is an error to return the address of or a reference to a local variable.

Only partially implemented.

Comment: "It is an error to use a local variable without first assigning it a value": You're right, this doesn't make any sense for default initialized variables. I think the only case where the compiler could error is if you explicitly initialized the variable with `= void` before reading it.

Comment: Well, the default initialization is meant to be a way to help catch uninitialized variable bugs! That's why char's default is not zero, but rather an invalid utf-8 code unit. That's why floats default to NaN, so their usage becomes immediately apparent. But there is no NaN or null for int... it just becomes 0, which is actually quite useful so now people depend on it as a convenience feature rather than a bug-finding feature!

Comment: What Adam said. It also helps writing some specific code faster such as having a variable declared before a scope. You won't need to set a default value to it that will get override anyway eg. let's say in a static loop. Most compilers that detects uninitialized variables ex. the C# compiler won't detect that ex. the loop would always execute.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen a compiler that generates a error for an unused variable. Warnings for sure but errors no.

I suggest you to try [Dscanner](https://github.com/Hackerpilot/Dscanner) which detects them, although it sometimes gives a wrong warning, particularly if used as a out parameter.

Comment: I do not believe any D compilers, but compilers for other languages does eg. C#.